# Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-testing-library

I'm using `ignite` to create an `expo react native` app. I'm using this guide https://ignitecookbook.com/docs/recipes/GeneratorComponentTests to create component test files

Here is the first test file

```
import React from "react"
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react-native"
import { HelloWorld } from "../HelloWorld"

describe("HelloWorld", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    render(<HelloWorld />)
    expect(screen.getByText("Hello")).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

I followed https://reactnativetesting.io/component/setup/ in order to install `@testing-library/react-native` but now I'm getting

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/montylennie/AbutFrontend/app/components/specs/HelloWorld.spec.tsx:12
            (0, react_native_1.render)(<HelloWorld_1.HelloWorld />);
                                       ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1518:14)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
```

Here is my `jest.config.js` file

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require("ts-jest/presets")

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.ProjectConfig} */
module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: "jest-expo",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|native-base|react-native-code-push)",
    "jest-runner",
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/.maestro/", "@react-native"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/setup.ts"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest-setup-after-env.js"],
}
```

And here is my contents of `jest.config.js`

```
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install `@testing-library/react-native`?

Comment: It's generally frowned on to edit in a way that changes the core question (both are problems with testing with Jest in an Expo-generated app, but different problems). I don't use Expo — did it give you a Babel config? The various config files in [this directory](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/tree/main/examples/basic) are a good reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems with your `jest.config.js` file:

- You are mixing two presets: `jest-expo` for Expo apps and `ts-jest` for TypeScript apps. This can cause conflicts or unexpected behavior,
  because they might have different settings or transformations. You
  should only use one preset at a time, or use the projects option to
  separate different sub-projects.
- You are using the `transformIgnorePatterns` option to tell Babel to
  ignore some modules. But this option only works for the default
  transformer, which is `babel-jest`. If you are using a different
  transformer, like `ts-jest`, you need to use the `transformerConfig`
  option to pass the ignore patterns to it.
- You are using the `testEnvironment` option to set `jsdom`, which is a
  browser-like environment for testing web apps. But you are testing a
  React Native app, which is a mobile app that runs on native
  platforms. You should use the node environment instead, which is the
  default for Jest. Or you can use the `react-native` environment, which
  is provided by the `jest-expo` preset.

To fix these issues, you need to update your `jest.config.js` file and choose the right options for your project. For example, if you are testing an Expo app with TypeScript, you could use something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-expo",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      transformerConfig: {
        transformIgnorePatterns: [
          "<rootDir>/node_modules/(react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|native-base|react-native-code-push)",
          "jest-runner",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/.maestro/",
    "@react-native",
  ],
  testEnvironment: "react-native",
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/setup.ts"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest-setup-after-env.js"],
};
```

Comment: Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated. Please do
`transform: {
    <transform_regex>: ['ts-jest', { /* ts-jest config goes here in Jest */ }],
}`

Comment: tansform was what i needed for using `babel-jest`, thanks!!